# Filter list view from edit text

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-edittext

I have an edit text as a search bar and a list view that filters the text that I typed but unfortunately, it doesn't filter the list view. I have used an customize array adapter with object Friend. **Friend object has name, address and phone number** but I only want to filter its name. In my activity...

```
searchBarTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    friendListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}}
```

While in adapter...

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "begin getFilter");
        if(newFilter == null) {
            newFilter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d(TAG, "publishResults");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

`@Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                Log.d(TAG, "performFiltering");

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                Log.d(TAG, "constraint : "+constraint);

                List<ChatObject> filteredFriendList = new LinkedList<ChatObject>();

                for(int i=0; i<friendList.size(); i++) {
                    Friend newFriend = friendList.get(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "displayName : "+newFriend.getDisplayName().toLowerCase());
                    if(newFriend.getDisplayName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "equals : "+newFriend.getDisplayName());
                        filteredFriendList.add(newFriend);
                    }
                }

                FilterResults newFilterResults = new FilterResults();
                newFilterResults.count = filteredFriendList.size();
                newFilterResults.values = filteredFriendList;
                return newFilterResults;
            }
        };
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "end getFilter");
    return newFilter;
}`

Could someone please help me how to correctly show the filtered array adapter? I think the notifyDataSetChanged is not invoked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem is solved, found out that I have to override **getCount()** and **getItem()**.

Comment: Thank you so much. My suspicious was that this was the culprit and this fixed my issue.

Comment: could you explain how you override the getCount()? the Filter object doesn't have a count, but the FilterResults object does.

Comment: Can you send me link or any referense for listview filter in android