# Searching in list not working in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have list view and its adapter stored as global variables. I am not creating my list by extending `ListActivity`. My code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle...) {
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    //setting my custom array adapter...works fine.
    //also my custom adapter implements Filterable interface
    mListView.setAdapter(...) 
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //My edit text where I enter my query
    mSearchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    mSearchEditText.addTextChangedLIstener(myListener);
}

private TextWatcher myListener = new TextWatcher () {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        }
        else {
            mListView.setFilterText(s.toString());
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

My problem is when I enter my string in edit text, it gives me correct no of available search items (only number) in my list but not the items itself.

For example if my list has items **aa, bb, cc, dd, ff, ee, ee**

So if I search for **ee**, my result will be **aa, bb** and not the **ee, ee**. And if I search **cc**, my filter list will show **aa** only.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a working example, try this:

```
filterEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.filter);
filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {  

        }  
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {  
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }  
    };
```

The adapter must `implements Filterable`

```
            @Override
            public Filter getFilter() {
//              Filter filter = null;

                if(filter == null)
                    filter = new CheeseFilter();
                return filter;
            }
```

And the filter class:

```
        public class CheeseFilter extends Filter {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                FilterResults newFilterResults = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {


                    ArrayList<String> auxData = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        if (data.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            auxData.add(data.get(i));
                    }

                    newFilterResults.count = auxData.size();
                    newFilterResults.values = auxData;
                } else {

                    newFilterResults.count = data.size();
                    newFilterResults.values = data;
                }

                return newFilterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                ArrayList<String> resultData = new ArrayList<String>();

                resultData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

                EfficientAdapter adapter = new EfficientAdapter(context, resultData);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

//              notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
```

You can check this post for more info:

[Filter expandableList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775774/custom-expandable-list-view-with-child-search-filter)

[Filter ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658751/filter-list-view-from-edit-text)

Answer (score 0):

Mate you will need to set it on the adapter not the listview directly.
So keep a reference of the adapter you set for your listview and try something like this in your text change listener:

```
private TextWatcher myListener = new TextWatcher () 
{

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
       myadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already but it has two issues:

1. Same as I mentioned above.
2. Also when I clear my text from edit text, my list view is not  seen completely.

Comment: hmm i guess then you could try this. This does it in the old fashioned way : http://androidsearchfilterlistview.blogspot.co.uk/