# Live Search Mechanism in Edittext in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have e project where I have a Edittext from where i have to get input on every keypress or something like every character input.And Have to perform a livesearch. What kind of Listener i have to use to get input for every character input .

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do this way**

```
editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable edit) {
                if (edit.length() != 0) {
                     // Business logic for search here
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically
>   while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a
>   drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the
>   content of the edit box with.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Here is a good tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/example-of-autocompletetextview.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'TextWatcher' as I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355971/how-to-filter-listview-through-edittext/10357473#10357473)

It will give you result as shown in below images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: note, however, using EditTexts is not a standart way of filtering ListViews

Comment: @pskink: kindly have a look at question.as per the requirement,`EditText` is involved.

Comment: kindly have a look at question.as per the requirement, no ListView is involved., so using EditText for filtering ListViews is a bad idea

Comment: I'm looking more something very similar to this however you can see the results here bring back anything that contains the letter 'm'. How would it be possible to return results that being with letter 'm', since this is the first letter typed - would that need implementing a custom query mechanism ?

Comment: @Samuroid: checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118309/how-to-use-search-functionality-in-custom-list-view-in-android/14119383#14119383) . you need implement `getFilter()` method and also need to replace `data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())` with `data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())`

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String textl = edittext.getText().toString().trim();


            }
        });
```