# How do I search any character in my search strings?

Tags: android, regex, android-layout, android-fragments

I am currently using a character sequence to search fro my strings. How do I search with any character in my strings? For Example: I have names " Justin " and "Jacks", if I put "k" only jack shows up, when I put "s" both justin and jacks show up since they have the letter s, if I put us only justin shows up and so on. How do I go about it?
Here's my code so far:

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
```

Here's the whole example sample code I used for my test project:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: just use yourName.contains(cs) in your filter to retrieve the items that match that sequence.

Comment: how do  i do that? can you give me an example with code?

Comment: you have a simple example here that should be useful: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html. you should apply that condition in the "performFiltering" method.

Comment: is there any simpler way to do it with regular expressions in the textchanged part?

Comment: post you full code maybe I can help to write an simple function for this request

Comment: actually i am using this code to test as a sample project: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ any changes with the above scenario will be awesome

Comment: I have created a test project.  Hopefully this will help https://github.com/nak411/AndroidFilterListDemo

Comment: @JusticeBauer: Did you try the code at [*Providing Auto-complete Suggestions*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete)?

Comment: @JusticeBauer: you are simply looking for this : [example code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10357473/1288725)

Comment: is there a way I can retrieve those names from a dummy database instead of defining them exclusively in the code? Is there an example for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the below code in your adapter to get filter data in the list:

```
        private Filter mFilter;
        private List<String> mCompleteList,mList;

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.values = mCompleteList;
                    results.count = mCompleteList.size();
                } else {
                    List<String> beanList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (String bean : mCompleteList) {
                        if (bean.toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                            beanList.add(bean);
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = beanList;
                    results.count = beanList.size();
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mList = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
    return mFilter;
}
```

And there is no need of MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); in text change you can just use adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); since adapter is your private variable of class.

Comment: is there a way I can retrieve those names from a dummy database instead of defining them exclusively in the code? Is there an example for that?

Comment: yes you can fetch these values from database you can fetch all values in start and save in arraylist and then same as above example will work for you or you can use cursor adapter for this if you want to fetch values at runtime when user type character

Comment: is there an example code available for that which I can refer?

Comment: you need example to make list from data obtain from database?
I am not clear for what you need example since i have already give example to filter data. please make clear you want adapter to filter data or way to call method to filter data.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write some sample code for your case.

```
String[] names = {"Justin","Jacks"};
String searchKeyword = "k";

for ( int i = 0; i < names.length; i ++ ){
     if (names[i].contains(searchKeyword) == true)
          System.out.print(names[i]);   // print out match results
                                        // system will print "Jacks" only
}
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to work, products is throwing errors in  inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
   }
   
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
     int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

After

`lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);`

just add this line as mentioned below,

`lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`

Thus, you will have results similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357473/1288725) example.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button android:id="@+id/addBtn"
            android:text="Add planet"
            android:onClick="addPlanet"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is your dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPlanet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Insert your planet name" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is your img_row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/planet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is your row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is your Planet.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 jfrankie (http://www.survivingwithandroid.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.survivingwithandroid.listview.SimpleList;

public class Planet {

    private String name;
    private Integer distance;
    private String descr;
    private int idImg;



    public Planet(String name, Integer distance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public Planet(String name, String descr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    public Planet(String name, Integer distance, String descr, int idImg) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.descr = descr;
        this.idImg = idImg;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public int getIdImg() {
        return idImg;
    }
    public void setIdImg(int idImg) {
        this.idImg = idImg;
    }


}
```

This is your PlanetAdapter.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 jfrankie (http://www.survivingwithandroid.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.survivingwithandroid.listview.SimpleList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements Filterable {

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    private Filter planetFilter;
    private List<Planet> origPlanetList;

    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.img_row_layout, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.origPlanetList = planetList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return planetList.size();
    }

    public Planet getItem(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_row_layout, null);
            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView distView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dist);


            holder.planetNameView = tv;
            holder.distView = distView;

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
            holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();

        Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        holder.planetNameView.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());


        return v;
    }

    public void resetData() {
        planetList = origPlanetList;
    }


    /* *********************************
     * We use the holder pattern        
     * It makes the view faster and avoid finding the component
     * **********************************/

    private static class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetNameView;
        public TextView distView;
    }



    /*
     * We create our filter 
     */

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (planetFilter == null)
            planetFilter = new PlanetFilter();

        return planetFilter;
    }



    private class PlanetFilter extends Filter {



        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = origPlanetList;
                results.count = origPlanetList.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<Planet> nPlanetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();

                for (Planet p : planetList) {
                    if (p.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nPlanetList.add(p);
                }

                results.values = nPlanetList;
                results.count = nPlanetList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                planetList = (List<Planet>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And This is your MainActivity.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 jfrankie (http://www.survivingwithandroid.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


package com.survivingwithandroid.listview.SimpleList;

/**
 * @author Surviving with android (jfrankie)
 *
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // The data to show
    List<Planet> planetsList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    PlanetAdapter aAdpt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initList();

        // We get the ListView component from the layout
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
        // Context
        // Data list
        // The row layout that is used during the row creation
        // The keys used to retrieve the data
        // The View id used to show the data. The key number and the view id must match
        //aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, planetsList);
        aAdpt = new PlanetAdapter(planetsList, this);
        lv.setAdapter(aAdpt);

        // React to user clicks on item
//        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//
//          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
//                  long id) {
//              
//              
//              // We know the View is a <extView so we can cast it
//              TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;
//
//              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item with id ["+id+"] - Position ["+position+"] - Planet ["+clickedView.getText()+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//          }
//         });

          // we register for the contextmneu        
          registerForContextMenu(lv);

          // TextFilter
          lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
          EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt);          

          editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    System.out.println("Text ["+s+"] - Start ["+start+"] - Before ["+before+"] - Count ["+count+"]");
                    if (count < before) {
                        // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
                        aAdpt.resetData();
                    }

                    aAdpt.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }


     // We want to create a context Menu when the user long click on an item
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
        Planet planet =  aAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options for " + planet.getName());
        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Details");
        menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Delete");

    }




    // This method is called when user selects an Item in the Context menu
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        planetsList.remove(aInfo.position);
        aAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }


    private void initList() {
        // We populate the planets

        planetsList.add(new Planet("Mercury", 10));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Venus", 20));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Mars", 30));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Jupiter", 40));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Saturn", 50));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Uranus", 60));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Neptune", 70));


    }


    // Handle user click
    public void addPlanet(View view) {
        final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        d.setTitle("Add planet");
        d.setCancelable(true);

        final EditText edit = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlanet);
        Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String planetName = edit.getText().toString();
                MainActivity.this.planetsList.add(new Planet(planetName, 0));
                MainActivity.this.aAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged(); // We notify the data model is changed
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });

        d.show();
    }


}
```

That's it.

Comment: is there a way I can retrieve those names from a dummy database instead of defining them exclusively in the code? Is there an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working sample,

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            MainActivity.this.adapter.filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

Within your adapter create your own filter method,

```
 public class FieldsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> mainDataList = null;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    public FieldsAdapter(Context context,List<String> fieldList) {
        mContext = context;
        mainDataList = fieldList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(mainDataList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mainDataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mainDataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_field_item, null);
            holder.txtFieldName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_field_name);         
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }       
        holder.txtFieldName.setText(mainDataList.get(position));        
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView txtFieldName;            
    }   

    public void filter(String queryText){
        queryText = queryText.toLowerCase();
        mainDataList.clear();
        if(queryText.length()==0){
            mainDataList.addAll(arrayList);
        }else{
            for(FieldsPOJO field:arrayList){
                if(field.getFieldName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(queryText)){
                    mainDataList.add(field);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }       
}
```

If you have any doubt please feel free to post your queries in the comment section. Happy coding..

Comment: is there a way I can retrieve those names from a dummy database instead of defining them exclusively in the code? Is there an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ModelFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<UserCommunicationStatus> filteredItems = new ArrayList<UserCommunicationStatus>();

            for (int i = 0, l = AllcommuserList.size(); i < l; i++) {
                UserCommunicationStatus m = AllcommuserList.get(i);
                String name = m.getFirstName().toLowerCase() + " " + m.getLastName().toLowerCase();
                if (name.contains(constraint))
                    filteredItems.add(m);
            }
            result.count = filteredItems.size();
            result.values = filteredItems;
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                result.values = AllcommuserList;
                result.count = AllcommuserList.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is my implementation, and I got the same results which you asked, I hope this would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the default Arrayadapter class in android only seems to search from the beginning of whole words but by using the custom Arrayadapter class, you can search for parts of the arbitrary string.
I have created the whole custom class and released the library.
It is very easy to use.
You can check the implementation and usage from [here](https://github.com/mohitjha727/Advanced-Search-Filter/blob/master/README.md) or by clicking on the link provided below.

https://github.com/mohitjha727/Advanced-Search-Filter

You can refer to this simple example-

We have names " Mohit " and "Rohan" and if We put " M" only then Mohit shows up in search result, but when we put "oh" then both Mohit and Rohan show up as they have the common letter 'oh'.

Thank You.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think you are right. I should add the essential parts of the answer here only. I appreciate you for the suggestion.