# SearchView with border and text

Tags: java, android, searchview

I want to make my `SearchView` like this:
[image]

How can I implement in `Java` ?

Comment: You want to create the search view inside java and not XML?

Comment: Of course XML. But Java too if it need some config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the image is the Material `TextInput` with `OutLined` style. You can read more about that and the `Filled` style in the official docs [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/#outlined-text-field).

Also, don't forget you'll need material library for this. For that, do

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```

[image]

Now, what you can do with it is to make it like above by adding `startDrawable` and `CornerRadius`:

1. Create the XML widget as below and put a `startIcon`.

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/editTextLayout"
       style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearanceOutLined"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Search View"
       app:hintEnabled="true"
       app:startIconDrawable=" *** Your ICON *** ">

         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
   ```
2. Then, this is the style `TextInputLayoutAppearanceOutLined`, put it in your style.xml file:

   ```
   <style name="TextInputLayoutAppearanceOutLined" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
   <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
   <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>

   <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
   <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="startIconTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>

   <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/_26sdp</item>
   <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/_26sdp</item>
   <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/_26sdp</item>
   <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/_26sdp</item>

   <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">1dp</item>


   <item name="hintEnabled">true</item>
   <item name="hintAnimationEnabled">true</item>

   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   ```

Obviously, you can set this in XML as well, but style gives you more control over your app to change the element everywhere by one edit.

1. Now, you'll have what you want your `SearchView` to look like, but further to make it act like a `SearchView`, you need to set filtering for your `ListAdapter` to make it work.

For that, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355971/how-to-filter-listview-through-edittext).

Answer (score 1):

make search view in layout file first

```
        <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round"/>
```

then the make drawable and name it bg_round and put the code below to that drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#fff"/> // this the the inner background color
      <stroke android:width="5dp" //this is for the stroke of the border
      android:color="@android:color/black"/> //this is the stroke color
      <corners android:radius="4cdp" /> //this is the corner radius
    </shape>
```