# Data Filter in list view through spinner

Tags: android, filter

I want to filter data in a list-view when i select a class from spinner. Any sample project or any link which is related to this, please provide me. [image]

i have data like in this format. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking there ----> on the right side, will give you a number of **Related** questions. Check them out.

Comment: Do you have the custom object arrayList or independent arraylists? For Leeson Class Description etc?

Comment: have you seen this thread ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658751/filter-list-view-from-edit-text?rq=1

Comment: I need filter via spinner. Here is edit text.

Comment: Hello Friends, I want Filter list view from Spinner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658751/filter-list-view-from-edit-text?rq=1 this have edit-text.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these: [Search In ListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/) or [Custom ListView Filters](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html).

Also,from your requirements, AutoCompleteTextView is more suitable than Spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't detailed your question but i think you want to select a class from spinner and according to that selection you want to update the "listview" only for the class, selected from spinner.

If I'm right then it is very simple,

First of all you have to update your arrayList<> only for the selected classes (Here your logic will work, It's on you to choose whatever algorithm.)

Secondly, Update your list-adapter using following methods-

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

It'll again call your adapter for updated arrayList<> and now it's done. :)